# How to exit GNU parallel when the programmer wants?

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

GNU parallel has options to exit the program based on jobs being finished or not, but is there an option to exit and kill all jobs whenever I want?

I want to exit GNU parallel and all processes when for example I finished doing something. So let's make it simple, I want to exit GNU parallel when string in one of the jobs is equal to "a1". Can GNU parallel accomplish this basic logic?

```
fun1() {
    if [[ "$var1" == "a1" ]]; then { exit parallel and jobs } fi
}
export -f fun1
parallel --exit_when_programmer_wants fun1 ::: $var1
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Using `{= perl expression =}` replacement strings you can run any perl statement and access any internal function. The functions that are supported are in `man parallel`, but you can call any function you want.

Here we do a hard exit when we hit 14:

```
$ seq 100 | parallel -j10  'sleep 0.1;echo {= $_ == 14 and exit; =}'
1
2
3
4
```

The reason why job 5-13 is not printed is due to GNU Parallel buffering jobs. So job 5-13 are started, but GNU Parallel exits before printing them. They are, however, not killed.

This is more visible if we disable buffering:

```
$ seq 100 | parallel -u -j10  'sleep 0.1;echo {= $_ == 14 and exit; =}'
1
2
3
4
5
$ 6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
```

Job 6-13 are put in the background so the output mixes with the command line (see 6).

A less hard way is to set `$::Global::start_no_new_jobs`:

```
$ seq 100 | parallel -j10  'sleep 0.1;echo {= $_ == 14 and $::Global::start_no_new_jobs=1; =}'
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
```

Or you can activate the logic in `--halt soon,done=1`:

```
$ seq 100 | parallel -u -j10  'sleep 0.1;echo {= $_ == 14 and $opt::halt="soon,done=1"; ::parse_halt(); =}'
1
2
3
4
5
parallel: This job finished:
sleep 0.1;echo 5
parallel: Starting no more jobs. Waiting for 9 jobs to finish.
6
parallel: This job finished:
sleep 0.1;echo 6
parallel: Starting no more jobs. Waiting for 8 jobs to finish.
7
parallel: This job finished:
sleep 0.1;echo 7
parallel: Starting no more jobs. Waiting for 7 jobs to finish.
8
parallel: This job finished:
sleep 0.1;echo 8
parallel: Starting no more jobs. Waiting for 6 jobs to finish.
9
parallel: This job finished:
sleep 0.1;echo 9
parallel: Starting no more jobs. Waiting for 5 jobs to finish.
10
parallel: This job finished:
sleep 0.1;echo 10
parallel: Starting no more jobs. Waiting for 4 jobs to finish.
11
parallel: This job finished:
sleep 0.1;echo 11
parallel: Starting no more jobs. Waiting for 3 jobs to finish.
12
parallel: This job finished:
sleep 0.1;echo 12
parallel: Starting no more jobs. Waiting for 2 jobs to finish.
13
parallel: This job finished:
sleep 0.1;echo 13
parallel: Starting no more jobs. Waiting for 1 jobs to finish.
14
parallel: This job finished:
sleep 0.1;echo 14
```

If you want GNU Parallel to do the killing of children use `--halt now,done=1`:

```
$ seq 100 | parallel -j10  'sleep 0.1;echo {= $_ == 14 and $opt::halt="now,done=1"; ::parse_halt(); =}'
1
2
3
4
5
parallel: This job finished:
sleep 0.1;echo 5
```

Or you can simply `kill` GNU Parallel. It has the benefit of being a supported feature, but has the buffering issue as shown in solution 1:

```
$ seq 100 | parallel -j10  'sleep 0.1;echo {}; [ {} -eq 14 ] && kill -TERM $PARALLEL_PID'
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
```

If you make your jobs only fail when you want to exit, you can use `--halt now,fail=1`:

```
$ seq 100 | parallel -j10 --halt now,fail=1 'sleep 0.1;echo {}; [ {} -ne 14 ]'
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
parallel: This job failed:
sleep 0.1;echo 14; [ 14 -ne 14 ]
```

But if you know GNU Parallel should stop when meeting a special string, a better way is to use `-E string`:

```
$ seq 100 | parallel -j10 -E 14  'sleep 0.1;echo '
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
```

It has the benefit of being fully supported and tested in every release.

Comment: This only exits based on passed value in arguments to parallel program, not inside programmer's function, but ok.

Comment: @CuriousPanda You are looking for `kill $PARALLEL_PID`. See above